# Codeigniter's db queries. (Order by)

Tags: database, codeigniter, group-by

I have a little query about Codeigniter's db queries. (Order by)

```
$this->db->select('*, MONTH(date) as mnth');
$this->db->where('school_id', $school_id); 
$this->db->group_by('MONTH(date)'); 
$this->db->order_by('date', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get('events');
```

In above piece of code i want to get events with respect to each month but it is returning me only the first event of each month.. I have tried it with php loops but i want it without loops.. Hoping for good responses.

Best Regards

Muhammad Saud

Comment: `GROUP BY` is messing with your query, not `ORDER BY`. Look into its documentation to see why.

Comment: Thanks Cryode for replying.

I looked into it, but there is nothing related to my problem in there.. if you have understand my problem.. then please suggest an answer if you can.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` will aggregate all of the column values that match the parameter into one row. You generally need to use aggregate functions like `SUM` in the `SELECT` statement with `GROUP BY`. If you're selecting columns that aren't being used with an aggregate function, then you'd include them in the `GROUP BY`. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I don't think the `GROUP BY` is doing what you'd expect - maybe try removing it (or add more column names to it).

Comment: Thanks Lefters,

I have a table named 'Events', which contains some events with date. I want to get events of each month separately using just db queries. I have done it using for loops, but it will eventually became slow with a large bunch of data. Please suggest some solution for this.

Comment: No worries. Try removing the `group_by` and add another `where` that will accept a specified month as a parameter and filter the results based on that month. It might be helpful if you posted what results you are currently generating and what you expect to get.

Comment: I want like as follows:
    $events['januaray'] = array of events in January
    $events['februaray'] = array of events in February
    $events['martch'] = array of events in martch
and so on.... I want the $events array in return.

Comment: If I understand what I think you want to achieve, then I don't think it's possible. Either generate the results you want from the database using the `where` clause, as I suggested above, or iterate through all of the results and create the resultant array that you want.

Comment: To generate the `$events` array that you want, I'd just iterate through the results from your query and create the new array.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries, I hope my answer helped!